# Language for cross-platform install script

Tags: cross-platform, installscript

In writing an install script, I quickly found that I'd have cross-platform issues, and bash scripts are hard to maintain.  I decided to look for a cleaner solution that's more cross-platform.

The goal is to have an intelligent script sniff out components of the user's system and have as little user interaction as possible.  That being stated, I thought about these languages:

- Python- cross-platform, and many other programs rely on it, so it may already be present
- Javascript- nodejs is required by part of my application, but it's a little clunky for exec calls

**Are there any languages that would be a better fit for this application?**

Requirements:

- Available on all platforms

  - May be distributed as part of my application if small enough
  - Little to no version variation, so Ruby is out
  - *nix only for now, but eventually will be run on Windows
- Maintainable

  - Clear syntax (Perl is out)
  - Modular (if I sniff the OS, I can include separate OS-specific code)
- Capable of downloading files (unmet dependencies)
- Capable of relatively complex scripting tasks

  - Testing for used HTTP ports
  - Reading and parsing files for configuration data
  - Checking for permissions and changing directories of insufficient privileges
- Open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python can do all of those things:

- Available on all platforms **(Mac, Linux, Windows, and more)**

  - May be distributed as part of my application if small enough **(You can make binaries with `cx_freeze`, if needed)**
  - Little to no version variation, so Ruby is out **(Python is pretty static when it comes to version changes)**
  - *nix only for now, but eventually will be run on Windows **(It comes pre-installed on Mac, and ships with just about any Linux distro. Binaries don't need the interpreter to run)**
- Maintainable

  - Clear syntax (Perl is out) **(Python is very easy to read, but that's up to you to decide)**
  - Modular (if I sniff the OS, I can include separate OS-specific code) **(Modules are just files in Python)**
- Capable of downloading files (unmet dependencies) **(`Urllib2` takes care of that, and it's pre-installed)**
- Open source **(Yep)**

Comment: I just started learning Python earlier this week. How simple is it to call native command-line applications (grep, sed, cat, etc)?

Comment: It's a bit hard to capture output of commands (not hard, but more than one line of code), so Python has most of those commands implemented one way or another. `cat` would be `open('file.txt', 'r').read()`. You'll find it awkward that it's not as easy as you'd like to call system commands (it's just `import os` and `os.system('foo')`, btw), but in the long run, native solutions are a lot easier to work with. **TL;DR: you'll pick that stuff up as you learn more about Python**

Comment: Ironically, the reason I considered Python in the first place is because I started some work in Blender. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Me too ;) It's a nice language, but I never really used it for Blender much. Maybe once for a 3D plotter, but that's about it. You'll love the way it doesn't break when you switch data types.

Comment: Like Javascript. It's nice to be able to assign stuff to a variable, instead of having to worry about types. I think Python my be the tool for the job, but I'll leave this open for a little bit just in case someone comes out with something better.

Comment: Never used Python for this purpose myself, so I think there should be competitors.

Answer (score 0):

Ant will do what you need.  It is OS independent and will allow compiles and installs.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with it. Does it allow relatively complex scripting (like downloading stuff from the web, scanning for HTTP ports, generating files based on user input)?